# Cannot connect to django rest api with react native network error

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm new with Django and React Native.
I try to make an app that sends data to django back end with axios but I have a network error.
I tried to change my localhost ip in 192.168.xxx but nothing change.

So I don't understand why I don't have any request.

Here is my code:

Django :

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8081',
    'http://localhost:19006',
    'http://localhost:19002',
    'http://192.168.101.6:19000',
)
```

Axios:

```js
import axios from "axios";
    
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.101.6:8080/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

requests :

```js
import http from "../http-common";
    
const getAll = () => {
  return http.get("/tutorials");
};
    
const get = id => {
  return http.get(`/tutorials/${id}`);
};
    
const create = data => {
  return http.post("/tutorials", data);
};
```

Comment: Did you add `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to your Django `MIDDLEWARE`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @marcus95 !

I think you made a typo mistake :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    ...
    'http://192.168.101.6:19000',
     http://192.168.101.6:8080,
)
```

Put `http://192.168.101.6:8080`, the same as in your axios configuration, in your CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST.